# Electron and Babel 6 async / await throw unexpected token

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, electron, ecmascript-next

I want to use async / await feature from ES7 in my Electron app, but it seems to be not working. It gives me

> Syntax error: unexpected token function

after command `npm start`..

Electron: v0.37.6
Node: v5.11.0 stable
Windows 10 x64

**main.js**

```
'use strict';

require("babel-core/register");
require("babel-polyfill");

(async function() {
  await console.log("test");
})()
```

**package.json** (snipped)

```
"devDependencies": {
  "babel": "^6.5.2",
  "babel-cli": "^6.7.7",
  "babel-core": "^6.7.7",
  "babel-eslint": "^6.0.3",
  "babel-plugin-syntax-async-functions": "^6.5.0",
  "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.7.4",
  "babel-plugin-transform-regenerator": "^6.6.5",
  "babel-polyfill": "^6.7.4",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
  "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.5.0",
  "electron-debug": "^0.6.0",
  "electron-prebuilt": "^0.37.0",
  "eslint": "^2.8.0"
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-3"],
  "plugins": ["transform-async-to-generator", "syntax-async-functions", "transform-regenerator"]
}
```

Have you any idea what's missing in my conf etc. please?

## Edit

I've also tried to add some `import` after `require()` but it ends with

> Unexpected token import

It seems to like Babe is not loaded at all..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved it in two easy steps:

1. puting my Babel stuff in seperate file

**index.js**

```js
'use strict';

require('babel-core/register');
require("babel-polyfill");
require("./src/main");
```

2. updated package.json to execute it on `npm start`

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "electron index.js"
},
```

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem.
Here is how I solved it: http://masnun.com/2015/11/11/using-es7-asyncawait-today-with-babel.html

**Edit**

`await` should be used with [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: Please put the answer (the way you solved the problem) in your post, [not only a link to it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/183280). You can [edit] your answer.

Comment: Although the link provides the answer, it is recommended that you add the main parts of the solution to your question, because there is not guaranty that the page will stay there.

Comment: @SashaBuzin thx, I've seen this article before and even that example doesn't work for me...but with different exception: Unexpected token import